# Accessing WordPress index.php responds with web site directory content files

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess

I've newly installed successfully and separately apache2.4, php7.4.7 and mysql8 on my Windows10 dev-machine to work on a wordpress project. The wordpress project template installation went well too but when i navigate to the project folder from the browser, it shows me the files in the project directory.

Clicking the index.php file give the same result (showing files in directory). I've been struggling for hours to find out what I did wrong but nothing. All suggestions on internet are about activating URL rewriting apache module, setting AllowOverride All and Require all granted everywhere in httpd.conf and adding a .htaccess file.

I did it all, the server reads the .htaccess file but nothing changes. I still can't see the home page of my web site even from the dashboard when i try to customize it. Can you please help telling me what i missed.

ALL REQUESTS TO index.php RESPONDS WITH LISTING FILES IN THE PROJECT DIRECTORY :

[image: Web site screenshot]

Here the content of my .htaccess file :

```
# BEGIN WordPress
# The directives (lines) between `BEGIN WordPress` and `END WordPress` are
# dynamically generated, and should only be modified via WordPress filters.
# Any changes to the directives between these markers will be overwritten.
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /kimea/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /kimea/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Comment: Looks like php is not registered in your setup.

Comment: it is. I had been able to install wordpress and even get to control panel.

Comment: Was that .htaccess generated by WordPress, or did you create the content yourself?